# Mutate ifelse to replace values in r

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that looks like the below:

```
Word     Value1   Value2

Apple    True     True
Chair    True     False
nonWord  False    False
Hat      False    True
...      ...
```

I'm attempting to change all the values of nonWords to `NA`'s.

```
data %>%
  mutate(Value1 = ifelse(Word == "nonWord", NA, Value1)) %>%
  mutate(Value2 = ifelse(Word == "nonWord", NA, Value2))
```

However, this does not seem to be working since my values are not being replaced by `NA`'s. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Desired output:

```
Word     Value1   Value2

Apple    True     True
Chair    True     False
nonWord  NA       NA
Hat      False    True
...      ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to use [`replace()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/replace.html) from `base R` rather than `ifelse()` for these cases:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Value1 = replace(Value1, Word == "nonWord", NA),
         Value2 = replace(Value2, Word == "nonWord", NA))

#>      Word Value1 Value2
#> 1   Apple   True   True
#> 2   Chair   True  False
#> 3 nonWord   <NA>   <NA>
#> 4     Hat  False   True
```

And if you're sure that all the columns you want to replace are named "Value...", you can take the advantage of [`mutate_at()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html) from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), ~ replace(., Word == "nonWord", NA))

#>      Word Value1 Value2
#> 1   Apple   True   True
#> 2   Chair   True  False
#> 3 nonWord   <NA>   <NA>
#> 4     Hat  False   True
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Word = c("Apple", "Chair", "nonWord", "Hat"), 
    Value1 = c("True", "True", "False", "False"), Value2 = c("True", 
    "False", "False", "True")), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a logical vector for rows in `i` (`df1$Word == 'nonWord'`), specify the column index in `j` (`-1` - implies not selecting the 1st column) and assign the values to `NA`

```
df1[df1$Word == 'nonWord', -1] <- NA
df1
#     Word Value1 Value2
#1   Apple   True   True
#2   Chair   True  False
#3 nonWord   <NA>   <NA>
#4     Hat  False   True
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
df1 <- df1 %>% 
       mutate(across(starts_with("Value"), ~ case_when(Word != 'nonWord' ~ .)))
```

---

In the OP's post, the replacement is happening, but the output is not assigned (`<-`) back to original object.  By default, `mutate` is not modifying `in place`.  If we want to do the in place modification, use `%<>%` from `magrittr` instead of `%>%`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Word = c("Apple", "Chair", "nonWord", "Hat"), 
    Value1 = c("True", "True", "False", "False"), Value2 = c("True", 
    "False", "False", "True")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```